# Gimp image color mode

Tags: indexing, rgb, photoshop, gimp

I use Gimp, I have a color pallet which contain 556 colors (embroidery related) , but I don't know how to use all those colors in my working image because the index color mode only support maximum 256 colors... what's the solution I have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

All the places in Gimp where the number of colors is limited seem to have an upper limit of 256 colors: indexed mode, color palettes, `Posterize` filter...

If you want to limit yourself to the 556 colors of your palette, create an image with 556 squares, each painted with one of your 556 colors and save it somewhere. Then when needed open it in Gimp together with your work image, and use the color picker to sample colors from it.

If you want to shoehorn an existing image into your 556 color palette, then you can use the [ImageMagick toolbox](https://imagemagick.org/) for this:

- Prepare an image with only your 556 colors (as a PNG file, you have to avoid JPEG because the compression will introduce extra colors). This will be your "color map". There is no need for a special format layout, the only important thing is that it contains only your 556 colors (to check in Gimp: `Colors > Info > Colorcube analysis`, with IM: `identify -verbose ColorMap.png` and check the `Colors` line)
- Execute the command

  `convert Source.png -remap ColorMap.png Reduced.png`

where:

- `Source.png` is your original image, with likely thousands of colors. It can be any format (JPG, PNG, TIFF...)
- `ColorMap.png` is the map you prepared above
- `Reduced.png` is the color-reduced image. It has to be in a format where pixel colors are preserved exactly (so, PNG in your case, for simplicity(*))
- In recent versions, `convert` is replaced by `magick` or `magick convert`

So for instance, starting with:

[image]

And applying this 512-colors colormap

[image]

You obtain this:

[image]

Note that the color-reduced image can contain much less than the 556 colors (190 colors in the image above, despite the 512 colors colormap) (you won't have bright reds in Mona Lisa).

The whole thing is documented [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#remap).

After trying the process a few times, I find that given a good palette it works quite well, so if your 556 colors make up good palette, you could make your workflow a lot simpler, by working in full RGB all the time, and then converting the image to 556 colors.

(*) TIFF and WebP formats also support exact colors/lossless compression, but they still have variants that will do a JPEG-like compression that will change the colors, so they must be used with care.

Comment: dear Xenoid ...  thanks for the response,  i already made 556 squares image from those  colors and that image used to generate the gimp pallet. however most of the creations are make from raster images.  almost nothing have draw or paint .  as example*  if i want to add famous 'Mona Lisa' paint  to my creation, then paint's colors should automatically convert to that pre defined 556 colors.

Comment: See augmented answer.